# my nodejs express application is being halted when executing select query (filtered using date column) send from my app to mariadb database

Tags: node.js, express, mariadb

please correct my query as the query is not being executed when send from nodejs app  to mariadb database . The query is

pool.query('select  * from item  where date >=? and date <=?',[startDate,endDate])

- above code  is located inside (app.get('/viewExpenses',function(req,res)

please reference the below code to solve this problem :

```
app.get('/viewExpenses', function (req, res) {
// Prepare output in JSON format
var startDate = req.query.startDate ;
var endDate = req.query.lastDate;
var result="<html><body><table><tr><th>item</th><th>date</th><th>category</th><th>cost</th></tr>";
var ob ;
pool.query('select  * from item  where date >=? and date <=?',[startDate,endDate])
.then(rows => {
    console.log("inside rows")
    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(rows[i]));
        ob = rows[i];
        result+="<tr><td>"+ob.iname+"</td>"+"<td>"+ob.date+"</td>"+"<td>"+ob.cname+"</td>"+"<td>"+ob.cost+"</td></tr>";
        console.log(i);
        console.log(ob);

    }
    result+="</body></html>";
    res.send(result);
   })
   .catch(err => {
    //handle error
   });
```

})

expected result :  select query is executed which is filtered by starting date and ending date

Comment: throw err in catch function and provide the err statement.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  With you suggestion , I console.log(err). And I have just found my error.Actually since I have typed " req.query.lastDate " instead of "req.query.endDate" hence my second parameter 'endDate' was undefined when the form was submitted using method="get".  I have now get my lesson. Always console.log (err) in catch statement to find the error.  Thanks again , Edwin Babu.